# How can I put a web part on an application page that can be deployed to any site?

Tags: application-pages, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have an XSLTListViewWebPart on an application page. Why I use visual studio to deploy it to the development site, it works fine, but when I use central administration to activate the feature on another site, and go to the application page, I get the error "the page you selected contains a list that does not exist."

Can anyone hint as to why this might be happening? I would paste in the web part code, but it's pretty long and I'm not sure it would be helpful.

I can confirm that the list I'm intending to use does exist on the site, but maybe I've got a relative reference to it that's not working properly, I guess. I just can't identify what property that might be. I've checked the `TitleUrl` `ListID` `ListUrl` and `ViewGuid` properties and they're all being set properly.

This is in 2010, but I'm not sure the issue is unique to 2010.

**Edit:** here's one of the web parts. There are actually three on the page, but they're all pretty basic and similar.

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" Description="My List Instance" ListDisplayName="" PartOrder="2" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True"
                        IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="False" IsIncludedFilter="" DataSourceID=""
                        Title="Product Sequences" ViewFlag="8388621" NoDefaultStyle="" AllowConnect="True" FrameState="Normal" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itgen.png"
                        PageSize="-1" PartImageLarge="/_layouts/images/itgen.png" AsyncRefresh="True" Dir="Default" DetailLink="{$SPUrl}/Lists/Product Sequences"
                        ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="64592f39-d6ae-43d7-b580-4b2b72b350d2" ListName="{64592F39-D6AE-43D7-B580-4B2B72B350D2}" FrameType="Default"
                        PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" ViewGuid="{2D64D56A-4E74-4DE6-94BF-13183A7C378F}"
                        AutoRefresh="True" AutoRefreshInterval="3600" AllowMinimize="True" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ViewContentTypeId="0x"
                        InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." HelpMode="Modeless" ListUrl=""
                        ID="ProductSequencesList" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" TitleUrl="{$SPUrl}/Lists/Product Sequences" ManualRefresh="True" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{2D64D56A-4E74-4DE6-94BF-13183A7C378F}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
                        <ParameterBindings>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
                    <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
                    <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
                    <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
                    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
                    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
                        </ParameterBindings>
                        <XmlDefinition>
                    <View Name="{2D64D56A-4E74-4DE6-94BF-13183A7C378F}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="" Url="{$SPUrl}/SitePages/RecipeManagement.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
                        <Query>
                            <OrderBy>
                                <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
                            </OrderBy>
                        </Query>
                        <ViewFields>
                            <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
                            <FieldRef Name="Vessel"/>
                            <FieldRef Name="Comments1"/>
                        </ViewFields>
                        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
                        <Toolbar Type="Freeform"/>
                    </View>
                        </XmlDefinition>
                        <DataFields>
                        </DataFields>
                    </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

And Because the guids change each time it's deployed - I have this utility method, called from the code behind:

```
// in code behind (Page_Load):
Utilities.ResolveWebPartList("Product Sequences", ProductSequencesList);
```

the utility method:

```
internal static void ResolveWebPartList(string listName, XsltListViewWebPart listViewWebPart)
    {
        using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            var theList = web.Lists[listName];
            if (theList == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("The specified list '{0}' does not exist in the site '{1}'.", listName, SPContext.Current.Web.Url));
            }
            listViewWebPart.TitleUrl = theList.DefaultViewUrl;

            listViewWebPart.ListId = theList.ID;
            listViewWebPart.ListUrl = theList.DefaultViewUrl;
            listViewWebPart.ViewGuid = theList.DefaultView.ID.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you add some code or something?

Comment: @Remko I said that I could post the web part markup, but it's long and I'm not sure it would be helpful. What part of the code would be helpful?

Comment: web.Lists[listName] results in an error when the list is not available better use web.TryGetList(listName).  Do you deploy this as a module or?

Comment: Is List 64592F39-D6AE-43D7-B580-4B2B72B350D2 on your production site, or is that a development GUID?

Comment: @Remko that code is working alright - it finds the list and gets the appropriate guids, etc. I actually *want* an error if the list doesn't exist.

Comment: @AronFoster that was actually just the initial guid of the list, but in the utility method, that gets overwritten for every page load, since the list gets a unique guid each time it's deployed.

Comment: @Remko It's deployed as a farm solution, activated as a feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in GUID formatting because

```
listViewWebPart.ViewGuid = theList.DefaultView.ID.ToString();
```

will format your view GUID like

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

and the GUID format should be

```
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

so you need to change your line to

```
listViewWebPart.ViewGuid = theList.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B");
```

Also take a look at this blog post:
[Programmatically create a SharePoint XsltListViewWebPart, with Cross-Site support](http://damneddutch.blogspot.com/2012/08/programmatically-create-sharepoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not fully apply as I was using a ListViewWebPart (not XsltListViewWebPart) but they are similar so it might help. The following code allowed me to use a ListViewWebPart from one site (with the embedded GUIDs in the source code) on a different site collection entirely:

```
listViewWebPart.ListId = theList.ID;
listViewWebPart.ViewGuid = theList.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
listViewWebPart.GetDesignTimeHtml();
```